# cannot find module '@storybook/react' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I was having the import error with "@storybook/react", but I managed to fix it.

`import { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react'`

In the terminal, run the command:

`npx sb init`

Hope this helps.

This is available at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/react

Comment: I'm still having issues with that.